# Transform an assignment problem to use the Hungarian algorithm

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, operations-research

I have this assignement problem:

> There are three machines to perform four tasks. The costs of assigning
>   to a machine each of the tasks are given by the following matrix:
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
>       2 & 6 & 4 & 4\\
>      3&4&4&3\\
>       2&5&6&5 \end{pmatrix}$$ $a)$ Determine an optimal assignement assuming that each machine must perform exactly one task and
>   therefore, one of the tasks will not be performed.
>
> $b)$ determine an optimal assigement assuming that each machine can
>   perform at the most two tasks and that every task must be performed.

So far, the assignement problems I've been asked to solve have a square matrix as the cost matrix, and each *agent* was required to perform exactly one task in a way that all tasks were performed and I would use the Hungarian algorithm to solve them. However, the algorithm works only for $n \times n$ matrix and I don't know how to proceed. So my question is:

> How do I transform this problem so I can use the Hungarian Algorithm to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a row with costs of 0. Any assignment to this row will be a task that is not done. Do something similar with columns in problem 2 - remember you will still need a square matrix though.

Comment: @Paul Thank you! So when the algorithm stops (the number of lines covering the zeros is equal to the number of rows), in the first problem I need to consider the row with costs of $0$ to construct the matching.  But in the second problem I don't how adding a column with costs of 0 solves it. Since I can make a machine perform two tasks, wouldn't the same argument (adding a $0$ row) work too?  I just need to mark two zeros on a single row so that each $0$ is in a different column, right?

Comment: Similar, but not the same problem. Your second problem will have 6 rows and columns. Ask yourself where the 6 rows are coming from and then add appropriate columns to make it square.

Comment: @Paul If I add only one row, I get a $4 \times 4$ matrix, and then each machine performs exactly one task. But I need a machine to perform two tasks so that the other two machines perform exactly one. So I add a new row and a new column to get a $5 \times 5$ matrix. But I can't see why I must add a new row...

Comment: @Paul Is it somehow related to the fact that I can assign two tasks to one machine in three different ways?

Comment: Count the three machines twice giving 6 rows. Add two columns of zeros to square it up. Assignment to these columns represent no job in the solution.